# Which routes are likely to be affected by British Airways union strike in December 2016?

Tags: air-travel, british-airways

British Airways' union has [announced a strike on 25-26 December](https://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/help-in-disruption/strike/latest-information) which could potentially disrupt flights.

> The trade union Unite has announced that it intends to hold industrial
>   action involving one of our five cabin crew fleets on Christmas Day
>   (25 December) and Boxing Day (26 December).

This appears to be [limited specifically to their "mixed fleet" crew](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-38347181). Which routes are likely to be affected if the strike goes ahead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's limited information available directly from British Airways on which routes are serviced long/short haul by their mixed fleet crew. [One source calls out the following routes / airports as affected](http://www.independent.co.uk/travel/news-and-advice/british-airways-strikes-which-what-christmas-new-year-flights-travel-plans-disrupted-affected-a7476416.html):

> UK Domestic: Aberdeen, Belfast City, Manchester
>
> Europe: Basel, Bergen, Bilbao, Bologna, Budapest, Dusseldorf, Gibraltar,
>   Gothenburg, Hamburg, Hannover, Helsinki, Kiev, Krakow, Lisbon,
>   Luxembourg, Marseille, Oslo, Paris Orly, Pisa, Prague, St
>   Petersburg, Stavanger, Stuttgart, Venice, Vienna, Warsaw, Zagreb
>
> US/Canada: Atlanta, Austin, Calgary, Chicago, Houston, Las Vegas,
>   Miami, Philadelphia, San Diego, San Jose, Seattle
>
> Latin America: Santiago
>
> Middle East: Abu Dhabi, Muscat, Tel Aviv
>
> Africa: Abuja, Cairo, Cape Town, Johannesburg, Lagos, Nairobi
>
> Asia/Australia: Bangkok, Seoul, Shanghai, Singapore, Sydney, Tokyo
>   Haneda

British Airways has already clarified [the following airports / routes are not affected](https://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/help-in-disruption/strike/latest-information):

> - All flights to and from London Gatwick will not be affected.
> - All
>     flights to and from London City will not be affected.
> - All flights to
>     and from Stansted will not be affected.
> - Flights operated by subsidiary
>     OpenSkies between Paris and New York will not be affected.
> - Flights
>     operated by British Airways franchise partners (Comair in South Africa
>     and SUN-AIR in Scandinavia) will not be affected.
> - Flights operated by
>     other carriers (including oneworld Alliance partners) which have a BA
>     codeshare flight number will not be affected.